# Vert.x 3 with SockJS - unable to establish connection

Tags: groovy, websocket, sockjs, vert.x

I am trying to run the simple example regarding websockets functionality using Vert.x 3.0.0 and SockJS 0.3.4 (I'm using groovy).

The groovy verticle looks like this:

```
import io.vertx.groovy.ext.web.Router
import io.vertx.groovy.ext.web.handler.sockjs.SockJSHandler

def router = Router.router(vertx)
def sockJSHandler = SockJSHandler.create(vertx, [heartbeatInterval: 2000])

sockJSHandler.socketHandler({ sockJSSocket ->
    sockJSSocket.handler(sockJSSocket.&write)
})

router.get("/").handler({req -> req.response().sendFile('ws.html')})
router.route("/myapp").handler(sockJSHandler)

vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router.&accept).listen(9090)
```

And on the client side (ws.html):

```
<html>
<head><title>Web Socket Test</title></head>
<body>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sockjs/0.3.4/sockjs.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var sock = new SockJS('http://localhost:9090/myapp');

    sock.onopen = function() {
        console.log('open');
    };

    sock.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log('message', e.data);
    };

    sock.onclose = function() {
        console.log('close');
    };

    function send(message) {
        sock.send(message);
    }
</script>
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" name="message" value="Hello, World!"/>
    <input type="button" value="Send Web Socket Data" onclick="send(this.form.message.value)"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when the client tries to establish the connection, it requests URL `http://localhost:9090/myapp/info`, which results in a 404. I am aware that it's part of the SockJS protocol, but why doesn't the server side verticle handle it? Should I handle the "info" requests myself?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the given examples

https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/web-examples/src/main/groovy/io/vertx/example/web/realtime/server.groovy

You need to register a `SockJSHandler` on a wildcard address